# printing ascii values from argv string in a single printf call

Tags: c, argv

I want to print the ascii values of all the chars from a string received from argv, using only one printf call.

Something like this, but to print only the valid chars ( != 0 ) :

```
printf (" string is %s , in ascii = 0x%X %X %X %X", argv[1], 
          argv[1][0], argv[1][1], argv[1][2], argv[1][3]);
```

I don't want to use a for loop, from 0 to strlen(argv[1]). I need to use only one print call.

If the argv[1] = "a", then I want to print only: string is a , in ascii = 0x61

If the argv[1] = "ab", then I want to print only: string is ab, in ascii = 0x61 62

The problem is that I don't want to print garbage data

Comment: Going with the flow of the answer, if you know `argv[1]` exists and want it all in one construct, `char *ptr = argv[1]; for (printf("string is %s , in ascii = 0x", ptr); *ptr; printf("%X ", *ptr++));`. You should reword the "in ascii" part to something like "character codes", though, as ASCII isn't guaranteed to be in use.

Comment: The number of characters in the string is a run-time determined value. You cannot write a single statement at compile time that processes each string and doesn't contain a loop with a dynamic exit condition.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do this without a loop. `printf` will only look for a certain depth into the stack and will always print a set number of values. You cannot make it look for a variable number of values, so a loop is your best choice:

```
char *ptr = argv[1];
while (ptr) printf("%X ", *ptr++);
```

(technically, this is a `while` loop, not a `for` loop).

Comment: If the point is to have only a single printf() call for the sake of either performance or convenience, just use sprintf() and strcat() to pre-create the string.